# Selecting points within 2 buffers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I have 2 huge files of points (hundreds of thousands of points).  I need to determine a way to loop through all the points in one file and find all the points in the second file that are only a certain distance away.  So like within a distance outside the buffer.  Or on the outer edge of the buffer.

I am thinking of 2 buffers, one larger buffer and then one smaller buffer and then somehow subtracting the values.  No idea how this could be accomplished though.

The files are huge so I am also concerned in doing this the quickest way possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: And the software that you have access to would be....????

Comment: arcinfo, sorry forgot to mention

Comment: Is a programming solution acceptable?

Comment: buffering is slow... trying using 'Near'

Comment: I think the question could be changed to something like "How can I spatially join two large datasets".  In the details describe the join logic (more than a min distance but less than a max distance).

Answer (score 4):

**Generate Near Table (Analysis**) [ArcInfo only]

[image]

**This tool behaves the same as the Near tool**. However, instead of updating the input features, it creates a new output table. Moreover, it can find as many near features as specified **by the Maximum number of closest matches parameter.**

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001n000000.htm

Comment: a programming solution would be great as well

Comment: the Desktop Help link above has code samples

Comment: programming solution is at the bottom of the link for Python as Mike Toews mentions

Comment: Awesome, thanks everyone.  I had not ever used this function.

Comment: Ok, I have tried this solution and realize that it is not helping and I probably did not explain myself.

Comment: So here is a new description.  I have a shapefile with 300000 points and another with 500000 points.  I need to find the points in file 2 that are a certain distance away from the points in file 1.  Like say 4 kilometers away.  So I do not want returned the points that are closer or farther than 4 kilometers and I need multiple points returned.  So if each point in file 1 has 4 points in file 2 then I need to return 1200000 points.